# error on expo go using react-native-webrtc "Cannot read property 'senderGetCapabilities' of null, js engine: hermes"

Tags: react-native, webrtc, expo-go, react-native-webrtc

When I Import This statements

```
import {
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
  MediaStream,
  MediaStreamTrack,
  mediaDevices,
  registerGlobals
} from 'react-native-webrtc';
```

This error comes in my expo Go(In android mobile):

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'senderGetCapabilities' of null,
> js engine: hermes ERROR Invariant Violation: "main" has not been
> registered. This can hap pen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Met ro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerCompon ent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

```
"dependencies": {
    "@config-plugins/react-native-webrtc": "^7.0.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/dev": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/heebo": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/kanit": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/merriweather-sans": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/open-sans": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/patua-one": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/roboto": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/roboto-slab": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo-google-fonts/rubik": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "expo": "~49.0.8",
    "expo-camera": "^13.4.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.8",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^111.0.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.2",
    "validator": "^13.11.0"
  }
```

Platform Information:

React Native Version: "0.72.4"

WebRTC Module Version: "^111.0.3"

Platform OS + Version: windows: 10

expo Go: 2.29.6

chrome: 116.0.5845.141

But If I don't import `react-native-webrtc` then it runs smoothly.
I need to create functionality which uses `webrtc`though, how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you resolve it? I have been stuck with this problem for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

react-native-webrtc are native code, if you want to use it on Expo, your must use development build follow this Doc  https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/
and add permisson in app.json file like this

Comment: "permissions": [
        "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
        "android.permission.BLUETOOTH",
        "android.permission.CAMERA",
        "android.permission.INTERNET",
        "android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS",
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
        "android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW",
        "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
      ],

Comment: what I should do if i use config-plugin? I found out this type error show all the time if you try to apply any native module in expo directly (even they are not require to change any native part code).

was it about the permissions u mentioned? 
Since I think permissions should never affect you get null object from the module itself?